# How can I create the project in Eclipse-nsight which use both Intel C++ and CUDA C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda, intel, nsight

I want to use ICC (Intel C++ Compiler) with CUDA NVCC (nVidia C++ Compiler) on Linux in the Eclipse-nsight.

- I installed [CUDA 5.5 with Eclipse-nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and [Intel Cluster Studio 2013 XE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cluster-studio-xe)
- and then I installed plug-ins (ICC toolchain) in the Eclipse-nsight via menu Help-> Install New Software ... https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-linux-using-intel-compilers-with-the-eclipse-ide-pdf

Now I can create Intel C++ project or CUDA C++ project. But how can I create the project which can contain at the same time both. Cpp-files and. Cu-file, and which automatic compile Cpp-files by using ICC and Cu-file by using NVCC?

Which project should I create: Intel C++ or CUDA C++, and what should I do then?

(Or may be someone known how can I create the project in Eclipse-nsight which use both GCC and ICC, and it will help me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CUDA project properties, specify the ccbin NVCC command line flag.