# Different compilers for different files in one project in Nsight Eclipse Edition

Tags: eclipse, c++11, cuda, nvcc, nsight

Is it possible to have different compilers for different files in one project in *Nsight Eclipse Edition*? For instance, is it possible to edit, compile, link, and run the example [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/) in *Nsight* without having to explicitly use the command line?
The case I'm facing is that I need to use *c++11* headers in my cpp file, inside a CUDA project; but *nvcc* doesn't support it. So while I'm developing it in *Nsight*, I'd have to use command line to compile, link, and run the project.

Comment: One not-so-nice solution seems to be manually changing `makefile` for the project in the editor. Also I have found [this very relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23133335/2386951) but don't quite understand the answer.

Comment: That comment simply tells how to make NVCC use ICC for host code compilation. It will not enable (full) C++11 support as NVCC parser does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible for a variety of reasons...

One common solution is to split the project into two - one that produces static library and another that produces an executable and links to the static library. Then you put all your NVCC-compiled CUDA code into either project and C++11 code into another.